# Magento thumbmail quadrada

Tags: magento

estou criando uma loja virtual em `magento` utilizando o `tema porto`, mas estou com o seguinte problema: As imagens estão ficando retangulares e desproporcionais, segue uma foto de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para deixar um tamanho padrão para as fotos? algo quadradinho tipo 200x200

Comment: Já tentei mudar o codigo da imagem no list para keepFrame(TRUE) e os $ratio_width,$ratio_height para 150,150 e não resolve :(

Answer (score 0):

a alteracao q vc fez em $ratio_width e $ratio_height afetam a geracao do codigo em PHP... isso modifica a qualidade da imagem renderizada... mas nao afeta o tamanho de sua exibicao na tela/navegador.

o q controla o tamanho da imagem exibida, eh o HTML/CSS.

dependendo de como o tema foi criado... vc pode modificar o width e height destas imagens em um `style.css` proprio do tema (deve estar dentro do package theme porto).

procure pelo class da imagem (se houver).. vc deve encontrar o nome do class no html gerado no navegador (clicando com botao direito em cima da imagem).. deve ser algo parecido com "`class=product_image`".

ou entao `.product .img` dentro do style.css do tema.

em alguns casos (pq tudo depende de como o tema foi escrito)... o tamanho width e height estarao dentro da tag img do html, ex.: "`<img src='...' width='...'>`"
nesse caso vc precisa modificar direto no codigo HTML.

sucesso ai.